# HTML5 libraries (CSS/JS) for 'multi-pane layouts'

Tags: html, mobile-website

The [multi-pane layout](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html) is very common to mobile applications:

[image: Android example]

If you've used Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, or a host of other applications on a phone or tablet you'll be familiar with the style.

I want to implement this style of interface in a mobile version of a web site. I have a pretty clear idea of how to roll this from scratch, but that rather feels like re-inventing the wheel.

Are there any existing libraries that make this easier using HTML?

Is there a more consistent name (i.e. common to iOS, Win, RIM and Android) for this type of layout ("multi-pane layout" on Google turns up lots of Android app solutions, but I need this for a web site, not an app)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Enyo](http://enyojs.com/) supports multiple panels layout.